# Writing scripts on a busybox-based embedded linux

Tags: linux, shell, sh, busybox

I have a piece of hardware with embedded Linux on it, using `busybox` as its shell. I want to create some scripts to do some administration on this device and I found the shipped `busybox` does have `wget` supported.

When I try to create a script though, this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/busybox wget <args>
```

is the only way I can use it.

Is that the way to go, or can it be easier? I tried to use `#!/bin/busybox` (gives `applet not found`) and also just lose the `/bin/busybox` before `wget` (gives a `wget: command not found`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/busybox sh

wget <args>
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/busybox ash

wget <args>
```